# How To Print Out a Webform Results?

Tags: webforms

Using [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) I have created a questionnaire and now I need to be able to print the results on paper. My first solution was going to the result page print out from the browser. Unfortunately, this does not look good on a print when print out.

Here is how it looks like browser.

[image]

And I think this looks very decent and acceptable, but when I print this out it will looks like this.

[image] The print out cut most of my webform results and without all my results this is useless for me.

My second solution was to try it out the [Webform2PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform2pdf) module. However, every time I try to used it does not work for me.

I have try to print out the e-mail I get from webforms but the results are on plain text and the results from the e-mail does not looks very professional. These results are have to be very presentable on paper.

So my question is what is the good approach of printing out the webform results.

Comment: Is your theme defining a specific stylesheet for print? You could disable that, or modify it.

Comment: Right now, I'm using Seven theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to have the Webform2PDF working (I was using the wrong version) but the output of the pdf did not looks very appealing to me. So I decide to use the [print module](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) because it allows me to print out my webform result the same way it looks on my administration page.

Comment: care to share how you accomplished this?

Comment: Hey @jackrabbithanna, It's been almost four years. So I do not remember exactly how I did it. If I am not wrong, there was some issue with the version of Webform2PDF that I was using that was not the latest at the time and by updating to the latest that fixed my issue.

Comment: Have you tried to use the print module?

Comment: I figured it out, you can use a php snippet to tell the print module to place a pdf link on the page at the settings, admin/config/user-interface/print/ui , "Show link in system (non-content) pages" row,

Comment: <?php
$path = request_path();
$path_array = explode('/', $path);
if(!empty($path_array[0]) && $path_array[0] == 'node' &&
!empty($path_array[2]) && $path_array[2] == 'webform-results' && !empty($path_array[3]) && $path_array[3] == 'analysis') {
return TRUE;
}
?>

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to expose webforms results/submissions activating a complex (but effective) combination of Webform Mysql Views module, Data and Schema modules ...
as stated here for instance: https://www.drupal.org/node/1658784.
It works .. and you can just print your views results.

However, next time if I were you, would have assessed possibile alternatives to webforms.
Have you ever heard about Entity Forms Module?
It rocks, because it overcomes the above mentioned limitations, and also for other very good reasons, as mentioned here under:

- [Why Entityforms? The case for a Field and Entity based Survey System in Drupal](http://www.sixmiletech.com/content/why-entityforms-case-field-and-entity-based-survey-system-drupal)
- [WHY ENTITY FORMS?](http://italomairo.italomairo.com/en/content/why-entity-forms)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might be to create **charts** from the survey results of the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module, there are 2 alternatives to pick from:

- **[Webform Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_charts)** (used in about 400 sites), to display Webform results in a graphical manner using a charting library.
- **[Webform Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_chart)** (used in about 220 sites), which integrates with the "Analysis" tab of a Webform (created with the Webform module) to provide charts for each individual component's analytical data.

The Drupal 7 version of both modules, requires the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module (dependency).